# Why is $F_n = r^n$ a solution of the difference equation if $r$ satisfies $r^2-r-1=0$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

The following is from p.4 of  https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch3.pdf

> The terms in the Fibonacci sequence are uniquely determined by the linear
>   difference equation
>
> $$F_n − F_{n−1} − F_{n−2} = 0, n ≥ 3$$
>
> with the initial conditions $F_1 = 1, F_2 = 1$.
>
> We see that $F_n = r^n$ is a solution of the difference equation if $r$ satisfies 
>    $r^2 − r − 1 = 0$ which gives $r = \phi$ or −$\dfrac{1}{\phi}$ where $\phi = \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}\approx 1.61803$.

I'm unable to see why $F_n = r^n$ is a solution of the difference equation if $r$ satisfies $r^2-r-1=0$.

Comment: Do you mean $F_n$ not $F^n$? If so, plugging in $F_n=r^n$, we get $r^n-r^{n-1}-r^{n-2}=r^{n-2}(r^2-r-1)=0$ and clearly $r\ne0$.

Comment: See the answer at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145342/find-a-formula-for-the-nth-fibonacci-number?rq=1).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: Yes, I meant $F_n$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Multiply $r^2 − r − 1 = 0$ by $r^{n-2}$.

Comment: Multiplying $r^2 -r-1=0$ by $r^{n-2}$, I get that $r^{n}-r^{n-1}-r^{n-2}=0$, but I'm not sure how I would get that $F_{n}=r^{n}$ without first assuming that $F_n=r^{n}$ and then plugging this into  $r^{n}-r^{n-1}-r^{n-2}=0$

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the complete solution to a difference equation with two distinct roots in the characteristic equation is in the form $$A{r_1}^n + B{r_2}^n$$.

In your case, the distinct roots for $r_1$ and $r_2$ are $\phi = \dfrac {1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $-\dfrac {1}{\phi} = \dfrac {1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  Thus the complete solution is $$F_n = \dfrac {1}{\sqrt {5}} \left (\phi^n - \dfrac {1}{\phi}^n \right)$$